# Topology on Galois group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions, profinite-groups

Let $L/K$ be a galois extension, we defined an open neighborhood basis for every $\sigma\in Gal(L/K)$ as $\sigma Gal(L/E)$ with $K\subset E\subset L$ and $E/K$ finit and galois.
Now i want to verify, that this defines a topology.

So every $O\subset Gal(L/K)$ is open if and only if for all $\sigma\in O$ exist one Galoisgroup
$Gal(L/E)$ with $K\subset E\subset L$ and $E/K$ finit, galois such that $\sigma Gal(L/E)\subset O$.

I had shown that the intersection of open sets is open with the Composite field.
Now my question is how can i show that the infinit union of open sets is open.

Let $O_i$ some open sets then for $\sigma \in \cup_i O_i$ there exists $k$ such that $\sigma\in O_k$ and we can say $\sigma Gal(L/E_k)\subset O_k$ ($E_i$ field depending on $i$).
But i need an extension for all $\sigma\in \cup_i O_i$ i think about $Gal(L/\cap E_i)$ is this correct and how can i verify that ?

Comment: The neighborhood basis doesn't contain all the open sets, you need to consider all the infinite unions of neighborhoods and add them to the list of open sets. Same for the finite intersections.

Comment: Oh yes thank you, i think i understood it